# Case insensitive in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to select some rows in SQLite with case insensitive string. For example:

COLLATE NOCASE is working for "=", e.g.

```
SELECT id,name from trait WHERE name = "ratio" COLLATE NOCASE
```

But is not working for "in", e.g.

```
SELECT id,name from trait WHERE name in ("ratio") COLLATE NOCASE
```

I have to use "in" to select multiple values, e.g.

```
SELECT id,name from trait WHERE name in ("ratio", 'number') COLLATE NOCASE
```

How should I change my SQL script? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT id,name 
FROM trait 
WHERE UPPER(name) IN ("RATIO")
```

Answer (score 11):

The COLLATE NOCASE must appear directly after the expression it modifies.

When you write `name in ("ratio", 'number') COLLATE NOCASE`, the collation is applied to the *result* of the comparison, which is just a number 0 or 1; a collation has no effect there.

The IN operator uses the collation of the expression on its left side, so this is where the collation must be applied:

```
... WHERE name COLLATE NOCASE IN ('ratio', 'number')
```